# Why does my fan not work?

Tags: heater-blower

I've got a Nissan Micra E 03 reg & the problem is my fan doesn't work on settings 1 & 2 but does work on settings 3 & 4. Could you please tell me what has happened. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on user4546's answer...

The heater fan is controlled by a resistor pack located somewhere under the dashboard. This usually has 3 resistors for settings 1, 2 and 3, with setting 4 being a direct connection. With time, these resistors burn out and need to be replaced - and they almost invariably burn out in order, so setting 1 will fail first, then 2 (and you have seen) and so on...

To fix it, you can either replace the entire pack, or, in some cases, have the individual resistors changed. I can't tell from a quick googling if this is possible for that age of  Micra, but new resistor packs seem to be available from Nissan or various online suppliers - make sure you get the correct one, as it looks like '03 was the changover year between two generations of Micra (K11 and K12)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bad blower motor resistor

Comment: This sounds like the problem to me as well. You should be able to pick one up off of the internet fairly easily.

Comment: For a Micra, of course! You'd get one cheap off a breakers as well - they're very popular cars, so every scrapyard has one